# Trouble understanding NSOperation & NSOperationQueue (swift)

Tags: multithreading, swift

I'm having trouble understanding how to create a synchronous NSOperationQueue.
I've created a prototype that basically says:

- Create 4 operations that very long or very short to complete
- Regardless of time to complete, they should finish in the order they are created in the queue.

My NSOperation class is very simple:

```
class LGOperation : NSOperation
{
    private var operation: () -> ()
    init(operation: () -> ())
    {
        self.operation = operation
    }

    override func main()
    {
        if self.cancelled {
            return
        }
        operation()
    }
}
```

And my test class is also quite simple:

```
class LGOperationTest
{

    class func downloadImage(url: String)
    {
        // This is a simple AFHTTPRequestOperation for the image
        LGImageHelper.downloadImageWithUrl(url, complete: { (image: AnyObject?) in
            println("downloaded \(url)")
        })
    }

    class func test()
    {
        var queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        var op1 = LGOperation(operation: { self.downloadImage("http://www.toysrus.com/graphics/tru_prod_images/Animal-Planet-T-Rex---Grey--pTRU1-2909995dt.jpg") })

        var op2 = LGOperation(operation: { println("OPERATION 2") })

        var op3 = LGOperation(operation: { self.downloadImage("http://www.badassoftheweek.com/trex.jpg") })

        var op4 = LGOperation(operation: { println("OPERATION 3") })
        var ops: [NSOperation] = [op1, op2, op3, op4]
        op2.addDependency(op1)
        op3.addDependency(op2)
        op4.addDependency(op3)
        op4.completionBlock = {
            println("finished op 4")
        }

        queue.addOperation(op1)
        queue.addOperation(op2)
        queue.addOperation(op3)
        queue.addOperation(op4)     
        println("DONE") 
    }
}
```

So I would expect here is for the operations to finish in order, instead the output is:

- DONE
- OPERATION 2
- OPERATION 4
- finished op 4
- downloaded
  http://www.toysrus.com/graphics/tru_prod_images/Animal-Planet-T-Rex---Grey--pTRU1-2909995dt.jpg
- downloaded http://www.badassoftheweek.com/trex.jpg

WHY can't I make web requests fire synchronously with other code? (I know I can use completion blocks and chain them but I'd like to figure out how to do it with NSOperation)

Answer (score 0):

Operation queues are used to schedule asynchronous operations, primarily these operations may be long running and you don't want to block the current (typically UI) thread. Blocking the UI thread leads to unresponsive UI.

When you create 4 operations, when they finish is a factor of what is being performed. In your case, you have operations that are doing `println` (which is very fast) and you have operations that are downloading from the internet (which is very slow).

The whole point of the operation queue is to allow you to fire these operations asynchronously, and *whenever the operations complete*, fire the completion handler.

In other words, you do cannot control the sequence.

If you want to control the sequence, my suggestion is to do the following:

1. Start operation 1
2. In operation 1's completion handler, start operation 2
3. In operation 2's completion handler, start operation 3
4. In operation 3's completion handler, start operation 4

In this way, you still achieve the benefits of Operation queues (you do not block the UI thread), and you can chain the operations in order.